# Call javascripting and display result in right hand frame

Tags: javascript, html

I've a menu on the left side of a frame.
I'm trying to call a javascript that will load a new html in the right side of the frame generated from XML data and XSL template.

The code to do it in one page with fixed parameters works fine. The two issues I struggle with is:

- How to make it flexible so I can use a different xml data and template on the call to the script
- How to present the data in the right hand frame pane.

This is the code for the left hand pane:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function loadXMLDoc(filename)
        {
         if (window.ActiveXObject)
           {
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
           }
         else 
           {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
           }
         xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
         try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
         xhttp.send("");
         return xhttp.responseXML;
        }

       function displayResult(xmlid,xslid)
        {
         xml = loadXMLDoc("XMLDATA/xmlid");
         xsl = loadXMLDoc("XMLDATA/xslid");

         // code for IE
         if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
          {
           ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
           document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = ex;
          }
         // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
         else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
          {
           xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
           xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
           resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
           document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
          }
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="displayResult('XMLDATA/cdcatalog.xml','XSL/cdcatalog.xsl');">TEST</a></p>
    <p><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="displayResult('XMLDATA/cdcatalog2.xml','XSL/cdcatalog2.xsl');">TEST</a></p>

    <div id="example" />

  </body>
</html>
```

If I omit the both arguments in the script call:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="displayResult();">TEST</a>
```

and assign the data sources in the parameters here:

```
 xml = loadXMLDoc("XMLDATA/cdcatalog.xml");
 xsl = loadXMLDoc("XMLDATA/cdcatalog.xsl");
```

Then it works on the same page.

I'm not a programmer so some help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the variables that you're passing in, you're simply using static text.

At the start of `function displayResult(xmlid,xslid)` change...

```
 xml = loadXMLDoc("XMLDATA/xmlid");
 xsl = loadXMLDoc("XMLDATA/xslid");
```

To...

```
 xml = loadXMLDoc(xmlid);
 xsl = loadXMLDoc(xslid);
```

---

**Update** - in response to the OPs comments...

If you want to move elements around the page, I would seriously consider looking at [jquery](http://jquery.com/) which will easily allow you to [detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) the items and [append them to](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) another area.

For example...

```
$(function(){
  var $rightArea = $("#rightarea");
  $("#leftarea *").each(function(){
    $(this).detach().appendTo($rightArea);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that is one issue resolved. remaining issue I have now is that I want to push the info from the left frame to the right frame. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Sorry, there is not enough information in your question to know what you're trying to achieve.  There is nothing there that tells me what the "left frame" and the "right frame" is.

Comment: The main page is a frame with on the left side frame the above code. Once a user clicks a link, the result should display in the right hand frame not in the left hand frame.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "frame"?  As that is quite a specific thing in HTML, and is probably more complex that you intend.  Do you mean just a formatted area, using something like a `<div>`?  If so, I would seriously consider looking at http://jquery.com/ which will allow you to [detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) the object and [append it to](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) another area

Comment: And now I've written that, I'm starting to think you DO mean you're using `<frameset><frame>` setup. In which case, it's far more difficult to implement.

Comment: right, in that case I just keep it on one page. Like I said I'm not a programmer. :)

Comment: Yes, definitely try and avoid `<frameset>` if you can... it's considered a very old and outdated way of doing things.  Good luck with the rest of your project (and definitely give jquery a go if you have the time) :-)